# Again, the operation of receiving data from a website?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to receive data from "http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Program/Program.aspx?st=1" or "http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Program/Program.aspx?st=2". But how can I get the data with "weekac" code. I also want to receive the data with links.

```
Public Sub Iddaa_Sonuc()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long
For i = 3 To 3
    Sheets("@").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Dim d As WebDriver, clipboard As Object, ele As Object, ws As Worksheet, t As Date, html As HTMLDocument, weeks As Object
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 15
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("@")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "http://arsiv.sahadan.com/Iddaa/Program.aspx?st=1"
    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL, timeout:=90000
        Set weeks = .FindElementsByCss("#weekac option")
                    .FindElementsByCss("#weekac option")(i).Click
            Set html = New HTMLDocument
            t = Timer
            Do
                DoEvents
                On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = .FindElementByCss("#iddaa-tab-body #resultsList")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While ele Is Nothing
            If Not ele Is Nothing Then
                clipboard.SetText ele.Attribute("outerHTML")
                clipboard.PutInClipboard
                ws.Cells.UnMerge
                Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
                ws.Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1, 1).PasteSpecial
                Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
            End If
            Set ele = Nothing
        .Quit
    End With
    Cells.UnMerge
    Columns("A:A").Insert
    Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(R[-1]C[1]=""Saat"",RC[4]=""Kod""),RC[1],R[-1]C)"
    Range("A2").Copy
    Range("A2:A" & Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Columns("A:A").Copy
    Columns("A:A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Cells.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=""
    Cells.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=""
    Columns("B:B").Replace What:="PM", Replacement:=" PM"
    Columns("B:B").Replace What:="AM", Replacement:=" AM"
    Range("D:D,F:F,K:K,O:AB,AF:AZ").Delete
    Range("O1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-7]=""v"",""#"",IF(ISNUMBER(RC[-8]),IF(YEAR(RC[-8])=YEAR(TODAY()),CONCATENATE(DAY(RC[-8]),""#"",MONTH(RC[-8])),CONCATENATE(MONTH(RC[-8]),""#"",RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-8]),2))),SUBSTITUTE(RC[-8],""-"",""#"")))"
    Range("Q1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-8]=""v"",""#"",IF(ISNUMBER(RC[-9]),IF(YEAR(RC[-9])=YEAR(TODAY()),CONCATENATE(DAY(RC[-9]),""#"",MONTH(RC[-9])),CONCATENATE(MONTH(RC[-9]),""#"",RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-9]),2))),SUBSTITUTE(RC[-9],""-"",""#"")))"
    Range("S1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]=RC[-3],0,IF(RC[-4]>RC[-3],1,-1))"
    Range("T1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]=RC[-2],0,IF(RC[-3]>RC[-2],1,-1))"
    Range("U1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR(ISBLANK(RC[-12]),RC[-12]=""-""),0,IF(ISNUMBER(RC[-12]),IF(YEAR(RC[-12])=YEAR(TODAY()),VALUE(CONCATENATE(DAY(RC[-12]),"","",MONTH(RC[-12]))),VALUE(CONCATENATE(MONTH(RC[-12]),"","",RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-12]),2)))),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-12],""."","",""))))"
    Range("U1").Copy
    Range("U1:Z1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Range("O1:Z1").Copy
    Range("O1:O" & Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Columns("O:Q").Copy
    Columns("O:Q").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Columns("O:O").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("O1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="#", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Columns("Q:Q").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Q1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="#", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Cells.Copy
    Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Columns("G:N").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("@").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("@").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1:D1048576"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("@").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:CC1048576")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("D" & Columns("D:D").Find(What:="Kod", LookAt:=xlPart).Row & ":D1048576").EntireRow.Delete
    Range("A1:R" & Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Sheets("Y").Range("A" & Sheets("Y").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("@").Delete
    Sheets.Add.Name = "@"
    Sheets("@").Move Before:=Sheets(1)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next
End Sub
```

It's my code, but it's not working.

When you open "arsiv.mackolik.com/Program/Program.aspx?st=2" in the browser, when you move the mouse over the teams, a link such as "javascript: popBasketTeam (44)" seems to be the id of the 44 teams here. When I have this information, I can get the statistics of the team in the form "arsiv.mackolik.com/Basketball/Team/Default.aspx?id=44" . Make it clear you are after these numbers.

Comment: Please share your code and explain what isn't working. And try to ask only one question and make that question clear. At present this is too broad and unclear. Also, by weekac I assume you mean _Hafta_ selection. Make it clear if you are after one Hafta or all if that assumption is correct.

Comment: Dear Mr. @QHarr how nice to see you

Comment: I received the data of the program with the code you wrote earlier. but because of the lack of links and the difference in the number of columns I could not reach the result as I wanted. When I view the source of the site address, it uses an id named weekac in program selection by date. I want to get program data (with links) with this id. Thus, I want to reach the statistics of the teams with the numbers on those links.

Comment: The weekac codes relate to _Hafta_ and are available in a JSON response from the server:  https://pastebin.com/UNjJa0gH

Comment: Easiest might be to use selenium and loop selecting each of the Hafta dropdown options.

Comment: Seleniumla received data but did not have link addresses.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to show selenium script and indicate what you mean by link addresses.What links are you expecting? Can you give an example? By the way: the page is updated through Ajax when making Hafta selections; not by navigating to a new URL.

Comment: When you open "http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Program/Program.aspx?st=2" in the browser, when you move the mouse over the teams, a link such as "javascript: popBasketTeam (44)" seems to be the id of the 44 teams here. When I have this information, I can get the statistics of the team in the form "http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Basketball/Team/Default.aspx?id=44".

Comment: It is possible but please include your current code first.

Comment: I can't add the code. "Most of your question is code," it says.

Comment: Edit your question to include the other important info from your comment above: When you open "arsiv.mackolik.com/Program/Program.aspx?st=2" in the browser, when you move the mouse over the teams, a link such as "javascript: popBasketTeam (44)" seems to be the id of the 44 teams here. When I have this information, I can get the statistics of the team in the form "arsiv.mackolik.com/Basketball/Team/Default.aspx?id=44" . Make it clear you are after these numbers.

Comment: I've modified the code you've written, but it's not receiving data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can still make your question a lot clearer. From your final point/comments: You can use a css [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector to gather each of the team links and extract the required number from the href . Below, I gather a nodeList of the required elements and loop that extracting your numbers into an array  `codes`. In the other dimension I place the name associated with that code. You can then loop the first dimension of the array to generate your links by concatenating current array indexed value into URL string.

---

**Integrating with your selenium script:**

```
Dim list As Object, codes()
Set list = d.FindElementsByCss("[href^='javascript:popBasketTeam']")
ReDim codes(1 To list.Count, 1 To 2)
For i = 1 To list.Count
    codes(i, 1) = Replace$(Replace$(list(i).Attribute("href"), "javascript:popBasketTeam(", vbNullString), ")", vbNullString)
    codes(i, 2) = list(i).Text
Next

Dim newURL As String
'Now loop codes dimension 1 i.e.
For i = LBound(codes, 1) To UBound(codes, 1)
    newURL = "http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Basketball/Team/Default.aspx?id=" & codes(i, 1)
    ' Do something ........
Next
```

---

[image]

---

Without selenium:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetLinks()
    Dim sresponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, list As Object, i As Long, codes()

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Program/Program.aspx?st=2", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
       sresponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = sresponse
    Set list = html.querySelectorAll("[href^='javascript:popBasketTeam']")
    ReDim codes(list.Length - 1, 0 To 1)
    For i = 0 To list.Length - 1
        codes(i, 0) = Replace$(Replace$(list.item(i).href, "javascript:popBasketTeam(", vbNullString), ")", vbNullString)
        codes(i, 1) = list.item(i).innerText
    Next
    Dim newURL As String
    'Now loop codes dimension 1 i.e.
     For i = LBound(codes, 1) To UBound(codes, 1)
         newURL = "http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Basketball/Team/Default.aspx?id=" & codes(i, 1)
      ' Do something ........
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear mr. @QHarr Your code is as good as always, but I couldn't do what I wanted to do.

Comment: (1) https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvrtPxzojG1VrhtDs9PbhsyuL-UH I would like to transfer this web data to https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvrtPxzojG1Vrhy-D8lg9s8XsM_L this way.

Comment: and (2) https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvrtPxzojG1Vrh6JrG4yqYOw9-gW I would like to transfer this web data to https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvrtPxzojG1Vrh20avptnYWjzTSE in this way.

Comment: These are the two things I want to do.

Comment: I'm afraid there's another project. Should I open a new question?

Comment: Hi, Yes you should. Please be sure to include your code. Test values so we can try and duplicate. Be very clear what isn’t working and include html using snippet edit tool.

Comment: Let me know when posted and I will have a look.

Comment: I have no chance of writing advanced code like you. I'm probably going to try and modify your codes.

Comment: I don't know if I can make it.

Comment: I am not sure why you think you have no chance. You can study and try to understand the answers on StackOverflow. If you want help understanding existing answers you can stop by the [dawghaus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169987/dawgs-waffle-haus) and ask for help. And someone, possibly me, will help you. The important thing is to really try to understand what the code is doing. Look up things you don't understand. Ask questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, one of the most important problems, I don't know English and I try to explain my thoughts by translating from Turkish.

Comment: This is also true in understanding what is written.

Comment: Your English is good from what I see above. Writing a good question which states clearly what you are after requires practice and often many edits to get it to the best you can do.

Comment: I've written. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53686701/i-want-to-get-data-by-checking-the-boxes-on-the-web-pag to