# Getting data by checking the boxes on the web page

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get data for certain date ranges from a website. The site address is "http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Canli-Sonuclar". There are boxes in this address that should be selected or not selected. "Futbol (futbol-text)", "Basketbol (basketbol-text)" will be selected from these boxes. "Tarihe Göre (aOrderBydate)" will be selected. But "Duello (chkDuel)", "Iddaa (chkIddaa)", "Canlı (chkLive)" and "Seçili (chkSelected)" will not be marked. In line with these preferences, I would like to pass all the data in the "list-table" table together with the link addresses. For example, I'll take a month's data in one go and transfer it to the excel sheet. I haven't written a code about it or changed a code.

Comment: you need to write some code otherwise it is just asking someone to write it for you and you are unlikely to learn that way. Remember to include the relevant html using the snippet tool via [edit].

Comment: If you look at the code I wrote, you will see; After receiving data from the website, I can write simple-level vba codes for shaping and optimizing it. My problem is getting data from the web. I've modified and run some of the code you've written.

Comment: Share the code then but keep the code that is only relevant to this question.

Comment: On the one hand I'm trying to do something. I will add to my question.

Comment: Selenium attracted my attention after you said, I am researching Turkish sources. I'il try to learn. I'm just using the explorer right now.

Comment: I know, it's loading very slowly.

Comment: I'm watching a selenium video on the other side right now.

Comment: Ok. Well add the code you have when ready.

Comment: I will try my luck.

Comment: I couldn't get the data from the web. I've been trying to solve selenium for 4 days, but I failed.

Comment: I don't have any code. If I can download the data, I'll write code to edit the data I get.

Comment: My problem is getting the data on web pages (with links) to the excel page. I do the rest with trial and error.

Comment: Will you help.?

Comment: I will. It will be later today

Comment: Thank you. I want to get data on both today's and previous days. For example; I would like to receive the data for both December 13th and the data from 1 November to 1 December. For statistics.

Answer (score 0):

The following will make selections; has javascript to allow for wait for element to be clickable; makes the de-selections you specify; and shows you how to change the date back in one day increments.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MakeSelections()
    Dim d As WebDriver, t As Date, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, table As Object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    Const URL = "http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Canli-Sonuclar#"

    Const JS_WAIT_CLICKABLE = _
    "var target = this, endtime = Date.now() + arguments[0];" & _
    "(function check_clickable() {" & _
    "  var r = target.getBoundingClientRect(), x = r.left+r.width/2, y = r.top+r.height/2;" & _
    "  for (var e = document.elementFromPoint(x , y); e; e = e.parentElement)" & _
    "    if (e === target){ callback(target); return; }" & _
    "  if (Date.now() > endtime) { callback(target); return; }" & _
    "  setTimeout(check_clickable, 60);" & _
    "})();"                                      'by @florentbr

    Set d = New ChromeDriver

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        .Window.Maximize

        With .FindElementByCss("[data-cc-event='click:dismiss']")
            .ExecuteAsyncScript(JS_WAIT_CLICKABLE, 3000) _
        .Click
        End With
        .FindElementByCss("#chkSport1").ScrollIntoView

        With .FindElementByCss("#chkSport1")
            If Not InStr(.Attribute("class"), "selected") > 0 Then
                .Click
            End If
        End With
        With .FindElementByCss("#chkSport2")
            If Not InStr(.Attribute("class"), "selected") > 0 Then
                .Click
            End If
        End With
        With .FindElementByCss("#aOrderByDate")
            .ExecuteAsyncScript(JS_WAIT_CLICKABLE, 3000) _
            .Click
        End With
        With .FindElementByCss("#chkDuel")
            If InStr(.Attribute("class"), "selected") > 0 Then
                .Click
            End If
        End With

        With .FindElementByCss("#chkIddaa")
            If InStr(.Attribute("class"), "selected") > 0 Then
                .Click
            End If
        End With
        With .FindElementByCss("#chkLive")
            If InStr(.Attribute("class"), "selected") > 0 Then
                .Click
            End If
        End With
        With .FindElementByCss("#chkSelected")
            If InStr(.Attribute("class"), "selected") > 0 Then
                .Click
            End If
        End With

        Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        'go back a day at a time.Add a loop here to change multiple days.
        For i = 1 To 2
            If i > 1 Then
                .FindElementByCss("[onclick='gotoDate(-1);']").Click
            End If
            t = Timer
            Do
                DoEvents
                On Error Resume Next
                Set table = .FindElementByCss(".list-table")
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
                On Error GoTo 0
            Loop While table Is Nothing
            'other code
        Next

        Stop                                     '<== Delete me later

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Macro made selections in browser. However, it did not export the data in table to Excel.

Comment: Yeah... I wrote the rest of the code. You need to grab the info in the other code section

Comment: (    Dim s As String, html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Dim hTable As HTMLTable, clipboard As Object
    html.body.innerHTML = s
    Set hTable = html.querySelector("dvScores")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
    clipboard.PutInClipboard
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("@").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial)

Comment: on this line     clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML

Comment: You are going to need to do some of the work yourself with this.

Comment: Did that help? It sets a table so you only need to consider how to write out the rows and change to retrieve different tables.