# How to properly use ExecuteASyncScript in VBA Selenium?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, selenium, asynchronous

I have the below piece of JavaScript script. I'm using VBA for Excel (with Selenium) and what I want is to wait for the server response in the website before the macro in VBA goes to the next line. For that, I'm using MyVbaVar = ChromeDriver.ExecuteAsyncScript(script), where "script" is the code below.

From what I've read, I must indicate a callback somewhere in the script so that Selenium knows when to stop executing the script. However, I have no idea how to do that. I tried many ways, without success, and searched everywhere, but all solutions for this type of problem are in posts about Selenium for Python or JavaScript.

Any help here (even just pointing out how to correctly use the ExecuteAsyncScript with a simple example) would be much appreciated!

PS: I have tried this code with just ExecuteScript, but the macro goes to the next line without waiting for the website response, as expected.

```
   * some variable declarations here

   functionThatAwaitsResponseFromServer(){
      if(response){
         response_var = response;
      }else{
         setTimeOut(functionThatAwaitsResponseFromServer, 1000); //run function again if no response
      };
      return response;
   };

   functionThatRequestsSomethingToTheServer(){
      requestFromServer();
      myFinalResult = functionThatAwaitsResponseFromServer();
      return myFinalResult
   };

   return functionThatRequestsSomethingToTheServer();
```

Comment: @florentbr example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53766444/6241235

Comment: @florentbr thank you for the link. Unfortunately, I'm still lost on some aspects.What is the "flag" that lets Selenium know where to stop executing the script? Simply writing callback(VariableIWantReturned) works because "callback" is that flag?

Comment: No. In the example I shared it is where either of the exit conditions are met then use _callback(target); return;_